# "An item with same key has already been added" not getting this exception if adding duplicate object as a key in dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have just a silly doubt that below is my small piece of code.

```
IDictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
IDictionary<Demo, string> dic2 = new Dictionary<Demo, string>();
dic.Add("S1", "S1.1");
dic.Add("S1", "S1.1");
Demo d1 = new Demo() { MyProperty = 1 };
dic2.Add(d1, "1");
d1 = new Demo() { MyProperty = 1 };
dic2.Add(d1, "2");
```

So my question is i am getting exception at line no 4 which is correct according to dictionary concept that I can not add duplicate key in Dictionary however when I am trying to do same thing with object and object  with same name I am not getting any exception event Dictionary have now two object of same type and same name.

Please help to understand this concept.

Comment: Your `Demo` class doesn't override `Equals`+`GetHashCode`meaningfull(by checking the `Name`), so `Object.ReferenceEquals` is used which just checks if both are the same references. It is not the same because you use `new Demo()...`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: That would work as an answer. Answers as comments makes me sad that my upvotes don't mean as much. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting data into dictionary, `Equals` is used to check wheter key is unique.

In `string` `Equals` is implemented to check its value. That is why you cannot insert two strings into dictionary. What's more `string` is strange type - technically it is reference type, but acts like value type.

In bare object (or when not overriden), `Equals` is implemented to compare object by reference - it just checks wheter variabled points to the same area of memory (note: we are talking about classes, not structs :-)). So when you create two objects:

```
Demo d1 = new Demo() { MyProperty = 1 };
d1 = new Demo() { MyProperty = 1 };
```

There are two copies of that object in different place in memory, so `Equals` says: "That objects are different" - and you can add it to the dictionary.

You can of course change this behaviour by overriding `Equals` (and `GetHashCode` but here is skipped to keep answer clear) in `Demo`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    // If parameter cannot be cast to Demo or is null return false.
    Demo p = obj as Demo;
    if (p == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return (MyPropertyx == p.MyProperty));
}
```

Then:

```
Demo d1 = new Demo() { MyProperty = 1 };
dic2.Add(d1, "1");
d1 = new Demo() { MyProperty = 1 };
dic2.Add(d1, "2");
```

will not definitely allow to insert second value.

Comment: I wouldn't skip `GetHashCode` because it is essential here and doesn't work without. A dictionary first uses GetHashCode to find the key, so if you don't override it `Equals` will not be used at all. Apart from that you should always override both.

Answer (score 2):

In C# strings behave like value types which means that the value of the string is compared (which is called Value Equality), meaning:

```
var string1 = "S1";
var string2 = "S1";
Console.WriteLine(string1 == string2) // will output true
```

In the case of objects (such as your Demo object) by default when they are compared they are only checked to see if they are the same object (which is called Reference Equality), meaning:

```
var d1 = new Demo() { MyProperty = 1 };
var d2 = new Demo() { MyProperty = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(d1 == d2) // will output false
```

Now with objects you can implement Value Equality so that the above example will output true.

You can learn more about that with [this guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Well, change the first line to `object string1 = "S1";` and you'll get `false` too, because the `==` operator is overloaded to compare `strings` by value but not objects that are strings. `string1.Equals(string2)` would still return `true`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you are mistaken, if you change the first line you'll still get `true` because whenever strings are compared with each other they are compared by value, regardless of whether your variable is denoted as `object` or `string` due to the fact that string is a special type and the comparison is done using a virtual call.

Comment: Well, try it out, you get even a compiler warning about possible unintended reference equality comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You have two objects using the same *variable name* (`d1`) but they refer to different *instances* of an object - so there is no duplicate.

It also looks like you expect both objects to be the "same" based on both having a property `MyProperty` with the value `1`. This is not the case - the dictionary, by default, will use the references as the key, which are different as I mentioned above. To enable the dictionary to treat your two objects as the same you would need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class `Demo`